# Find a bunch of objects at once with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongo model and I would like to search for multiple objects with different properties at the same time.

```
model.find({uuid: 235q422462}, {uuid: 435q4235239}, function(err, objects){
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        console.log(objects)
    }
});
```

and then have it return both objects. Currently this is not working. Is there some way I can do this in mongo/mongoose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [$in](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in) operator:

```
db.model.find( { uuid: {$in:[235q422462, 235q422462}})
```

or the [$or](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator to achieve this:

```
db.model.find( { $or: [ { uuid: 235q422462 }, { uuid: 235q422462 } ] } )
```